# Regarding forward declaration c++ class

Tags: c++, forward-declaration

I have two classes like this:

```
class B;

class A {
public:
  int a, b;
  B *b;
public:
  int getctxt()
  {
     b->getctxt1();
  }
}

Class B {
public:  
  int c,d;
  A *a; 
  getctxt1()
  {
      /* something */
  }   
}

main()
{
  B *b = new B();
  A *a = new A();
  b->a = a;
  a->b = b;
}
```

But when I try to compile, it says

> invalid use of incomplete type ‘struct A’.

Can anyone tell me how to solve this?

Comment: Shouldn't there be a semicolon `;` at the end of each class declaration? ;-)

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19343279/circular-dependecies-in-c-classes-that-dpend-each-other

Comment: There is no invalid use of incomplete type ‘struct A’ in your code. There are lots of other errors, though. Please post code that is related to the problem description (or a problem description that matches the code).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inline class member function definitions are parsed as if they appeared right after the class definition. Of course `B` isn't defined at that point. So move the member function definition for `A::getctxt` out of the definition of class `A`:

```
class B;

class A { int getctxt(); /* ... */ };

class B { /* ... */ };

int A::getctxt()
{
    b->getctxt1();   // at this point, *b has complete type!
    return -35;
}
```

Comment: I did that. STill I get the same error :(.. I moved the definition of the getctxt() outside A.

Comment: @user1667630: Did you move it *past* the definition of `B`?

Answer (score 0):

This is the reason why it is recommended to separate your classes in a .h file and a .cpp file. When you write `class B;`, you are telling the compiler that there is a class called B, but that's it, the compiler does not know what is inside this class. When the compiler reaches the line `b->getctxt1();`, it knows that `b` is an instance of `B`, but it does not know if `getctxt1()` is a method of `B`, because that is below. If you are writing all in a single file, you should first write all the declarations, and then all the implementations.

Answer (score 0):

didn't anyone notice `Class B` syntax error? lowercase `class` is correct.
and those two public members in A with the same name `int b` and `B *b`.

once you remove those and finish class definitions with semicolons, add a void type to the `void getctxt1()` that is missing it in B.

just define functions as they should be defined. not inline without a reason that you know which is!